# RxJS DebounceTime doesn't work with interval

Tags: rxjs

I have one question regarding `debounceTime` and `interval` from rxjs.

Why `debounceTime` is not working with combination with `interval`?

E.g.

```
import {interval} from "rxjs";
import {debounceTime} from "rxjs/operators";

const int$ = interval(1000);

console.log("Start", Date.now());
int$.pipe(
  debounceTime(2000)
).subscribe(val => console.log("With Debounce", Date.now()))

int$.subscribe(val => console.log("Without Debounce", Date.now()))
```

In above case `"With Debounce"` will be never put into console.

Comment: Did you maybe confuse `debouceTime` with `delay` here?

Comment: @churill now I know that I should use `throttleTime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *[`debounceTime`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime)* - Emits a notification from the source Observable only after a particular time span has passed without another source emission.

Since your interval time is less than your debounceTime, no emissions will occur, because the time span is never exceeded without receiving another emission.

If you change debounceTime to 500, you will get emissions. however the effect would be the same as omitting debounceTime altogether.

I actually can’t think of a case where using debounceTime with interval would be useful.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @BizzyBob I wrongly understood how it works. Interval was just a simple representation of complicated Observable. I think that I should use ThrottleTime instead. Thanks Again!